# jsのイベントを調べる方法

Tags: javascript

今、あるページを作っていて、テキスボックスにテキスト入力をして、テキストが入っている状態で、そのページ内のどこかをクリックすると、そのテキストボックスの内容が消えてしまうので、その原因を調べるために、テキストボックスからカーソルが離れた時、クリックイベントやチェンジイベント等何が発生しているのかを全て調べたいのですが、どのようにすればいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

開発者ツールを使います。

・Firefoxを使う場合
FirefoxではF12キーを押すと出せます。「インスペクター」を参照し、その横のボタンを押すと、画面の要素(ここではテキストボックス)を選択できます。選択部分のコードが下または右に表示され、青くなります。

その横にeventとついていれば、これがその要素に関するイベントです。
もし`blur`というものがあれば、そのコードです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。見つかりました。

Answer (score 1):

Chromeであれば、コンソール内で、`getEventListeners`すれば出てきたような気がします。
`window.getEventListeners(document.body.getElementById("text"))`

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かにありました。